# Right-click menu not showing in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

On this [Selenium documentation page](https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export), it says "You can export either a test or suite of tests to WebDriver code by right-clicking on a test or a suite...", but when I right-click, I just get the web browser's right-click menu instead of Selenium-IDE's menu:

[image: browser's right click menu]

I have found that quitting Firefox and starting it again will give me the proper right-click menu, but wondered what I was doing to cause it, and if the developers know about this.

Firefox 71.0 (64-bit) on Windows 7

Selenuim IDE Version 3.16.1

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to export test from different tabs. 'Executing' tab is opened on your screen, but 'Tests' tab is opened on documentation screenshot .

About restarting Selenium IDE: 'Tests' tab opens as a main window after restart, so exporting is available there. When you start running tests in Selenium IDE 'Executing' tab automatically opens and exporting is not available. You should change tab by clicking on the tingle near tab name and select 'Tests' tab where you can export your test.

If you think that this is not correct behavior you should create issue [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues)